# Bad border behavior using "display: table-cell"

Tags: css, css-tables

I'm currently working on a project where I have to build a large-data table using `<div>` elements. I won't use semantic `<table>` (it's for some personal project and lab).

I did succeed with the main table structure, using the useful `display: table` property but I'm encountering some difficulties when I try to apply CSS border style to the cells (fiddle link at the end of this post). The cell's width and height are increasing and I'm not able to avoid it playing out with the border properties.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Main Container -->
<div class="main-container">
  <!-- Table container (where the display: table is applied) -->
  <div class="table-container">

    <!-- First row -->
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Second row -->
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Third row -->
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica", "Open-sans", "sans-serif";
}

.main-container {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.table-container {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #dde1e3;
  overflow: visible;
}

.selected {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #00b9e6 !important;
  z-index: 100000 !important;
  background: #EBF7FF !important;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".table-cell").click(function() {
      $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
      $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lc0rE/9ntxmLk4/

Can you please help me to understand how to avoid to change both width and height of the cell I'm clicking on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box;` on `.selected`. It's a miracle worker:

```js
$(".table-cell").click(function() {
  $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica", "Open-sans", "sans-serif";
}
.main-container {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.table-container {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.table-row {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
}
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #dde1e3;
  overflow: visible;
}
.table-header {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.selected {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #00b9e6 !important;
  z-index: 100000 !important;
  background: #EBF7FF !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}
.selected-remove-border {
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="table-container">
    <div class="table-row table-header">
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
        <div class="draggable-container">
          <div class="draggable-bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
        <div class="draggable-container">
          <div class="draggable-bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
        <div class="draggable-container">
          <div class="draggable-bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
        <div class="draggable-container">
          <div class="draggable-bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
        <div class="draggable-container">
          <div class="draggable-bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
        <div class="draggable-container">
          <div class="draggable-bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
        <div class="draggable-container">
          <div class="draggable-bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
        <div class="draggable-container">
          <div class="draggable-bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
        <div class="draggable-container">
          <div class="draggable-bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
        <div class="draggable-container">
          <div class="draggable-bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
        <div class="draggable-container">
          <div class="draggable-bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <span>Table cell</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works like a charm! Cannot believe the power of single property! :) Thanks

Comment: @Lc0rE, awesome. I'm glad it worked. You're welcome.

Comment: In the .selected class, changing the display to table-cell will correct the alignment issue.

Comment: thanks @TimBarnett. Actually, if I put the `display: table-cell` I have this strange behaviour: https://snag.gy/9yAzwH.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @lonut but also, have you thought about not using a border? Here is an example using `box-shadow: inset ...`. The benefit is, its a shadow, not a border, so it doesn't take up any of the space of the cell, which may be useful for not messing with the position of any text.

It's purely presentational rather than affecting the way the cell displays.

Code:

```
.selected{
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #ff0000;
}
```

So that means:

- `inset` – shadow the interior rather than the exterior
- `0` – pixels on the x axis, so line up with the element
- `0` – pixels on the y axis, so line up with the element
- `0` - blur, so have a solid appearance
- `3px` - spread, so fill 3px (you can think of this in your case as `border-width`)
- `#ff0000` - make the box-shadow red

Here is a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/9ntxmLk4/1/

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Actually, I did try to achieve what you posted without good results. I like the box-shadow effect and I think it could work for my purposes! But there is a small detail that is driving me crazy: a single pixel is missing from the right side of the box-shadow... why?

Comment: Everything looks fine on my end : ) no extra pixels at all. What browser are you using?

Comment: Here you are: https://snag.gy/ADKU1r.jpg I'm using Chrome and I did set the box-shadow to 1px wide! Thanks for the patience :)